# How to track all places where a class variable is modified by external code?

Tags: c++, debugging, runtime

Assume I have a class definition like this:

```
class A {
private:
    Field f;
public:
   /*A hundred methods all of which modify f*/

    m1();
    m2();
    ...
    m100();
}
```

We know before hand that all of these methods, if called, will modify f.

Assume you have a very spaghetti code base.

You need to find at runtime if and where f is actually modified.

You could use gdb, set a break point at every single method and see where execution stops and then unwind the stack to see which method called any of the m*() methods. This is very slow, prone to human error and not necessarily possible in a code base using emscripten, or where python calls the C++ binary after setting some state...

You could comment out all such methods and explore all places in the code where the compiler complains. This is, imho much worse than the prior, and it does do it at runtime, so it's harder to determine which method will ACTUALLY be called.

Similar as the above, you could mark all the above methods as deprecated, but it has more or less the same problems.

Does anyone have a suggestion on determining when and where the field actually gets modified?

Comment: Compile time is always best IMHO. You might also create "log" of accesses. On linux this can be done via backtrace. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html. Ad "which method will ACTUALLY" this can _actually_ change in time. If methods are unused remove them.

Comment: The thing is, this is for debugging, not for architecture design, I need to know when the field is changed TODAY, to figure out the source of the error, not to diagnose the quality of the code base.

Comment: Yup I realized later it's library used by ctypes. backtrace might help You, we used to use it log accesses to mutexes when we were switching from recursive to non-recursive ones over 50+ products. You just need to use version with symbols (which you would need in other cases anyway). Although it obviously won't give you stack trace of python... Maybe specify better your case for this.

Comment: A profiler should also let you know which methods were called, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `Field` directly, use a wrapper that lets you know whenever `f` is modified.  Something like (**very** crudely):

```
class FieldLogWhenModified
{
    Field data_;
public:
    FieldLogWhenModified(Field f) : data_(f) {}
    FieldLogWhenModified& operator=(const FieldLogWhenModified& new_f)
    {
        data_ = new_f.data_;
        // log or alert user in some way
        return *this;
    }
```

And/or perhaps:

```
    Field& operator=(const Field& new_data)
    {
        data_ = new_data;
        // log or alert user in some way
        return data_;
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is, if the field uses any other operator, now the wrapper must modify those operators as well.

e.g, the compiler won;t know how to execute multiplication or subtraction with an integer wrapper.

Although i like this approach a lot

Comment: @Makogan Sure, the wrapper must support all operators/functions that `Field` does.  But it simply passes those operations/functions to `data_` and returns the result after logging the event.

Comment: I know, as I said I like this approach a lot, I am just thinking it may be a bit cumbersome for data types that overload a lot of operators, like primitives or mathematical classes like matrices and vectors

Comment: It is. But then that's why you should have encapsulated accessors to begin with. If you didn't have 100 functions all modifying a primitive on their own then this wouldn't have been a problem ;)

Comment: Blame the author of the code base, I am just debugging it : p

Comment: I think you may have a typo, should it not be:

`data_ = new_f.f;` 

???

Comment: @Makogan Yes indeed, now fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On Intel (and perhaps some other) platforms, gdb supports the notion of *watchpoints*, i.e. a hardware breakpoint that fires when a particular memory location is written to.

The syntax for setting a watchpoint (without the square brackets) is:

```
watch -location [expr]
```

so in your case, something like:

```
watch -location my_object.f
```

Then run your code and note where it breaks into the debugger.

Documentation [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_29.html) and [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html)

Answer (score 1):

Is it `f` of one particular object of class `A`?

If yes, you can set up a [memory watch](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html#Set-Watchpoints). It will break the program whenever memory at a given address (occupied by your field `f`) is changed.

It may make your program go slower, but it may be worth it in your case.

Comment: No it is the f field in any arbitrary instance of class A